# html5 video presents jagged edges when scaled down

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, scaling

I have an html5 video that looks fine when played on media player (vlc, quicktime etc...)

It also looks fine on the web page at sizes over approximately 800px width.

However when scaled below 800px the edges of objects in the video look aliased and jagged. This is true cross browser.

When played via Vimeo however, even when scaled down the video looks fine.

Is there a way to remove this jagged edge? Why is the video playing this way in the html5 video player?

*Note: I believe Vimeo is serving video with an H.264 codec, I am using the same.*

[Image of Scaling Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbgAO.jpg)

Comment: I mitigated this problem by using SD video rather than HD video. Decreasing the quality made the video smooth when scaled down.

Comment: my guess would be that Vimeo will serve a lower resolution automatically, so delivering the same result you had. If you want/need to keep the higher quality and can serve it from somewhere appropriate you could look at HLS (though not supported across all browsers)

Comment: I assume the same, but it boggles my mind that something high resolution looks bad when made smaller. It defies common sense and comes down to a mathematic/software issue.